# Vaadin Rich Text Editor component markup buttons (Bold, Italic, etc) don't work on Safari

Tags: safari, vaadin, macos-big-sur, vaadin14

I can't be 100% certain, but having recently upgraded to Big Sur it now appears that the Vaadin rich text editor component (PRO) no longer works fully when using a Safari browser.

When attempting to highlight some entered text and setting it bold/italic/underlined or creating a hyperlink, the cursor jumps to a different position in the text and some other control buttons are highlighted (e.g. text alignment).

The same behaviour is not apparent when using a Firefox or Chrome browser under Big Sur.

Is there some special treatment now required for Safari, or is it a bug in Vaadin that the new version of safari has surfaced?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's a known issue that is currently investigated, see https://github.com/vaadin/web-components/issues/2115